# Take the information from json

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to parse "VID" from this json data 
`{"response":[2,{"vid":165971367},{"vid":165971350}]}`.
But it don't want to parse it. I think there is problem with "2" in json data. How to eliminate this figure?

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("some json data");
string googleSearchText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject googleSearch = JObject.Parse(googleSearchText);
IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["response"].Children().ToList();
IList<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is - your sample is valid JSON. There is no code shown so it is not possible to see if anything wrong with code either...

Comment: I want to how I can eliminate "2" and start from second object to parse data

Comment: I see - you use "parse" as "process data parsed by JSON.Net". I'm always confused by that type of usage of "parse", sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were usng Json.Net and loaded that json into a JObject then you have a property called "response" so:
myJson["response"]

which is a JArray with 3 elements, so skip the first element.
.Skip(1)
Then you have IEnumerable and want property "vid", so something like:

```
var myVids = (from vids in myJObject["response"].Skip(1)
               where vids["vid"] != null
               select vids["vid"])
/*  JSON

{"response":
   [2,
    {"vid":165971367},
    {"vid":165971350}
   ]
}

*/
```

Of course, this is just the concept and you would need to adjust for real life.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the first item by using [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method:

```
IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["response"].Skip(1).ToList();
```